# Average Word Length of Set of Strings

Tags: java, string

I am trying to get the average word length for a set of strings and I am running into an error below:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

I am not sure what it is caused by. Here is my code:

```
static double getAverageWordLength() {

    // TODO: update the code here to return the average length of words in the tweets processed so far.

    String[] average = tweeps.split(" ");

    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int currentWordLength;
    String tempString;
    for(int i = 0; i < average.length; i++)
    {
      average[i] = average[i].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase();
      tempString = average[i];
      currentWordLength = tempString.length();
      sum += currentWordLength;
      count++;
    }
    double averageWordLength = sum / count;
    return averageWordLength;
}
```

Comment: Which line of code does the exception come from?

Comment: Cannot reproduce in my environment. what is the value of `tweeps`?

Comment: By the way, `sum / count` is doing integer division (so it will truncate any numbers past the decimal point). You probably want `1.0 * sum / count` in order to promote the calculation to `double` before doing the operation.

Comment: The code above works in my environment @Jack, what's the value of tweeps?

Comment: `return Stream.of(tweeps.split("\\s+")).mapToInt(String::length).average().orElse(-1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.lang.*;

class test{

    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
       String MySentence = "This is My Word. I'm Going to Find the Average of this";
       System.out.println(" Average Length :"+ getAverageWordLength(MySentence));
    }

    static double getAverageWordLength(String tweeps) {

        // TODO: update the code here to return the average length of
        // words in the tweets processed so far.

        String[] average = tweeps.split(" ");

        int count = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int currentWordLength;
        String tempString;
        for(int i = 0; i < average.length; i++)
        {
          average[i] = average[i].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase();
          tempString = average[i];
          currentWordLength = tempString.length();
          sum += currentWordLength;
          count++;
        }
        double averageWordLength = sum / count;
        return averageWordLength;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: I pass "tweeps" as a parameter in main function like below   getAverageWordLength(MySentence).Then "tweeps" has a value when it execute.

Comment: I have tweeps as a static private string in my class and the function is within the class. Wouldn't that do the same thing as yours? I'm not sure if that is the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure about that.sorry